# Algorithm to find nth root of a number

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find nth root of a number. The answer must be an integer. I have found that newtons method and bisection method are popular methods. Are there any efficient and simple methods for integer output?

Comment: with integer means no decimal places?

Comment: @Ishmeet Yes Answer should be integer

Comment: So, do you want the result rounded, and if so, then how? Or do you want to get answer only if it is integer, and error (or whatever) otherwise?

Comment: @hyde Result must be rounded

Comment: Why close this question!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>
inline int root(int input, int n)
{
  return round(pow(input, 1./n));
}
```

This works for pretty much the whole integer range (as IEEE754 8-byte `double`s can represent the whole 32-bit `int` range exactly, which are the representations and sizes that are used on pretty much every system). And I doubt any integer based algorithm is faster on non-ancient hardware. Including ARM. Embedded controllers (the microwave washing machine kind) might not have floating point hardware though. But that part of the question was underspecified.

Comment: Might want to round the result instead of truncating: `(int)(pow(...)+0.5)`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes we aren't sure, are we?

Comment: @Madura I am sure, because I don't use compilers from the last millennium.

Comment: @rubenvb Why gave 1./n. I am a beginner :)

Comment: @user567879 The nth root of x is x raised to the (1/n)th power. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root.

Comment: @user567879 The maths: raising to a 1/n-th power is the same as taking the n-th root. That's by definition. In C(++), `1/n` is an integer division, whereas in `1./n` `1.` is a `double` literal, so `n` gets converted to a double, and then divides 1.

Comment: I'd prefer writing `1.0 / n`. It'll save a lot of people who might read the code a few "brain cycles" when they think what does this mean...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes good thing I checked, without -O2 or -O3 flags gcc 4.8.2 doesn't inline by default times were 2.114s and 2.092s(without and with inlining).

Comment: @MaduraAnushanga: Why would you compile without `-O2` or `-O3`? It seems obvious that if you compile without optimisations enabled then optimisations will not be performed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's the same reason why those flags exists in the first place, unless full optimization might have been the default.

Comment: Great benchmarking right there. As Scooter once said: "Statistically these are the safest cars on Pandora. Let me throw some numbers at you... Five! Twenty-three! Eight Hundred and Six!"

Comment: Whether `double` represents all `int` values exactly is implementation dependent.

Comment: It works for integer `input`. However, if the base is a float from a range (0.0, 1.0), the `pow` returns NaN (this sucks).

Answer (score 11):

I know this thread is probably dead, but I don't see any answers I like and that bugs me...

```
int root(int a, int n) {
    int v = 1, bit, tp, t;
    if (n == 0) return 0; //error: zeroth root is indeterminate!
    if (n == 1) return a;
    tp = iPow(v,n);
    while (tp < a) {    // first power of two such that v**n >= a
        v <<= 1;
        tp = iPow(v,n);
    }
    if (tp == a) return v;  // answer is a power of two
    v >>= 1;
    bit = v >> 1;
    tp = iPow(v, n);    // v is highest power of two such that v**n < a
    while (a > tp) {
        v += bit;       // add bit to value
        t = iPow(v, n);
        if (t > a) v -= bit;    // did we add too much?
        else tp = t;
        if ( (bit >>= 1) == 0) break;
    }
    return v;   // closest integer such that v**n <= a
}
// used by root function...
int iPow(int a, int e) {
    int r = 1;
    if (e == 0) return r;
    while (e != 0) {
        if ((e & 1) == 1) r *= a;
        e >>= 1;
        a *= a;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This method will also work with arbitrary precision fixed point math in case you want to compute something like sqrt(2) to 100 decimal places...

Comment: Is this shifting nth root algorithm?

Comment: fails for large integers - I tried this to get 111'th root of an 80-digit integer (string of 8 consecutive copies of "1234567890") which is 5, but got 1 from this routine. (my current routine took 12 minutes to finish, so I'm looking for a faster one :)

Answer (score 6):

I question your use of "[algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm)" when speaking of [C programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29). Programs and algorithms are not the same (an algorithm is mathematical; a C program is expected to be *implementing* some algorithm).

But on current processors (like in recent x86-64 laptops or desktops) the [FPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) is doing fairly well. I guess (but did not benchmark) that a fast way of computing the n-th root could be,

```
 inline unsigned root(unsigned x, unsigned n) {
   switch (n) {
     case 0: return 1;
     case 1: return x;
     case 2: return (unsigned)sqrt((double)x);
     case 3: return (unsigned)cbrt((double)x);
     default: return (unsigned) pow (x, 1.0/n);
   }
 }
```

(I made a switch because many processors have hardware to compute `sqrt` and some have hardware to compute `cbrt` ..., so you should prefer these when relevant...).

I am not sure that n-th root of a negative number makes sense in general. So my  `root` function takes some `unsigned x` and returns some `unsigned` number.

Comment: I [question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question) your [questioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question) of the term algorithm when speaking of any programs...?

Comment: Even when signed values make no sense, they're troublesome if you want to write clean code with no "risky" signed-unsigned conversions, unless *all* values really are unsigned, which they rarely are. An in this case, consider for example `cbrt(-8)`...

Comment: The use of the double-precision floating-point function `pow` here is specious and is **guaranteed to give you wrong results** on occasion, due to floating-point rounding error. For example, `(unsigned)pow(4096, 1.0/6)` is `3`, but the 6th root of 4096 is actually 4. This is because `pow` returns `3.9999999999999996` instead of `4.0`, which is because `1.0/6` is `0.1666666666666667` instead of exactly 1/6.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient general implementation in C, using a simplified version of the "shifting nth root algorithm" to compute the floor of the *n*th root of *x*:

```
uint64_t iroot(const uint64_t x, const unsigned n)
{
  if ((x == 0) || (n == 0)) return 0;
  if (n == 1) return x;

  uint64_t r = 1;
  for (int s = ((ilog2(x) / n) * n) - n; s >= 0; s -= n)
  {
    r <<= 1;
    r |= (ipow(r|1, n) <= (x >> s));
  }

  return r;
}
```

It needs this function to compute the *n*th power of *x* (using the method of exponentiation by squaring):

```
uint64_t ipow(uint64_t x, unsigned n)
{
  if (x <= 1) return x;

  uint64_t y = 1;
  for (; n != 0; n >>= 1, x *= x)
    if (n & 1)
      y *= x;
  return y;
}
```

and this function to compute the floor of base-2 logarithm of *x*:

```
int ilog2(uint64_t x)
{
  #if __has_builtin(__builtin_clzll)
    return 63 - ((x != 0) * (int)__builtin_clzll(x)) - ((x == 0) * 64);
  #else
    int y = -(x == 0);
    for (unsigned k = 64 / 2; k != 0; k /= 2)
      if ((x >> k) != 0)
        { x >>= k; y += k; }
    return y;
  #endif
}
```

Note: This assumes that your compiler understands GCC's `__has_builtin` test and that your compiler's `uint64_t` type is the same size as an `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this C function to get the **nth_root** of an unsigned integer :

```c
unsigned initial_guess_nth_root(unsigned n, unsigned nth){
    unsigned res = 1;
    for(; n >>= 1; ++res);
    return nth ? 1 << (res + nth - 1) / nth : 0 ;
}

// return a number that, when multiplied by itself nth times, makes N.
unsigned nth_root(const unsigned n, const unsigned nth) {
    unsigned a = initial_guess_nth_root(n , nth), b, c, r = nth ? a + (n > 0) : n == 1 ;
    for (; a < r; b = a + (nth - 1) * r, a = b / nth)
        for (r = a, a = n, c = nth - 1; c && (a /= r); --c);
    return r;
}
```

Example of output :

```
  24 == (int) pow(15625, 1.0/3)

  25 == nth_root(15625, 3)
   0 == nth_root(0, 0)
   1 == nth_root(1, 0)
   4 == nth_root(4096, 6)
  13 == nth_root(18446744073709551614, 17) // 64-bit 20 digits
  11 == nth_root(340282366920938463463374607431768211454, 37) // 128-bit 39 digits
```

Here is the github [source](https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-MathSnip/blob/main/simple_functions/nth_root.c).